# Longest Path, with Ascending Edges Weights, in Cyclic Undirected Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I want to find longest path in cyclic undirected graph. Each pair of edge is associated with a cost.

The constraint on traversing is that the weight should be in ascending order. Thus I want to find longest path with ascending weights.

Can we use DFS to solve the problem. I am trying to implement it but I don't know how to take care of cycles.

Comment: You're probably going to have to use branch-and-bound.

Comment: The longest path between two connected vertices in an undirected graph is always infinitely increasing (there is no "longest" path, as you can always find a longer path). Are you looking for the longest path without repeating edges between two given vertices? Or an "all-pairs" longest path? You could possibly use a modified Bellman-Ford algorithm. If you detect a cycle, you've found your "longest" path.

Comment: The total weight is the sum of the weights for consecutive pairs of edges?  i.e. if e[i] is the ith edge of the path, the total weight is `sum{i=1,n-1}(w(e[i],e[i+1]))`?

Comment: Branch, Block, Reach, Connect blocked paths, find the Longest one

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer Can you please elaborate as an answer

Comment: @user3634974 check my proposed algorithm..

Comment: Can a path repeat nodes as long as it doesn't repeat edges?

Answer (score 4):

If the only constraint of traversing is that the weight continuously increases, then you don't need to worry about cycles.  Eventually each cycle will terminate due to the fact that you entered a vertex on the highest weighted edge, and therefore there is no edge that is valid for exiting the vertex.

Comment: Can you elaborate little more. From where should I start?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a directed graph G' where vertices represent edges in the original one. In graph G' there is path from vertex A' to vertex B' if corresponding edges A->B create an ascending path. Now the problem can be stated as finding longest path in the graph G'. The graph G' is a DAG and we can sort it topologically and find the longest path in simple traverse.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach ..

**Branch**

```
stack = create empty stack
branched = create empty list
tree = create empty tree

stack.push({node=start_node, distanct=0, tree.root})
tree.root = start_node
branched.add(start_node)

while stack is not empty:
{
    current_node = stack.pop()

    if current_node is end_node:
        skip

    for each neighbour_node of current_node:
    {

        if neighbour_node is parent of current_node.getTreeNode():
            skip

        if neighbour_node exist in branched list:
            current_node.getTreeNode().addChild(neighbour_node, TYPE_LINK)
        else:
            current_node.getTreeNode().addChild(neighbour_node, TYPE_BRANCH)
            stack.push(neighbour_node)
    }
}
```

This branching is optimal, since whenever a visited node is branched, we will insert it in the tree as a `LINK`, which we will be using later on to maximize or minimize in order to find unique paths that contain no cycles between `start_node` and `end_node`.

**Optimization**

```
tree2 = create empty tree
tree2.root = empty_node

for each leaf in tree.getLeaves():
    if leaf is end_node:
        tree2.root.addPath(tree.getPath(leaf).reverse())

for each leaf in tree.getLeaves():
    if leaf is TYPE_LINK:
        L = tree2.findAll(leaf)    
        for each node in L:
            if L.getChildren() doesn't contain this node:
                L.addPath(tree.getPath(node).reverse())

solution = { none, 0 }

for each leaf in tree2.getLeaves():
    if leaf is start_node AND leaf.depth > solution.depth:
        solution = leaf

return solution
```

First we take `end_node` and form a `tree2`, first find direct paths toward `start_node`, then add liked paths as branches. Finally, we take the deepest `leaf`.